# ReactNative: Trying to debbug cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to debug my app. In the past everything worked perfectly. Then I formatted the computer, downloaded the project I had saved from git.

At this point, every time I try to run `npm start` in the terminal or to use the react native tool of visual studio code to debug the app or in any case to update the app connected to my device I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/..../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:338:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/react-native/cli.js:12:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/Users/..../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/package.json',
  requestPath: '@react-native-community/cli'
```

I don't understand how can I do.

I remember that before when I made a change to the code I just needed to run npm start to reload my project and see the changes in my device. Now I absolutely can't get the code and device to interact.

How can I do?

Comment: Re your deleted question: Aside from the `split(":")[0]` approach, you can also just do `const index = text.indexOf(":"); const time = index === -1 ? text : text.substring(0, index);` To do that on all elements in the array, you'd probably use `map`: `const result = elements.map(text => { const index = text.indexOf(":"); return index === -1 ? text : text.substring(0, index); });`

Answer (score 0):

You try reinstall React LI:

```
npm install –g react-native-cli
```

and install dependences:

```
npm install
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggest but when I do `npm start` I receive alwayse the same error